# why the set function "[*set(nums)]" showing different behavior with different inputs?

Tags: python

Input =>

```
nums = [1,2,2,100]

print([*set(nums)])
```

Output = >

```
[1,2,100]
```

Input =>

```
nums = [1,2,2,1000]

print([*set(nums)])
```

output =>

```
[1000,1,2]
```

i don't know the reason

Comment: `set` is not ordered. The order you get depends on how `set` hashes and buckets its input. There is no guarantee that it will remain the same on two consecutive accesses or that everything won't shuffle when something is added or removed.

Comment: "_i don't know the reason_" -> there is some explanation over in [_Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26099671/674039)